# Need to extract results from google keywords external tool?

Tags: java, network-programming, keyword, web-scraping

Need to build a little java tool that gets the keyword suggestions and traffic estimates from the google keywords tool at https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal .

The page is rendered in javascript so simple scraping isn't possible. I have tried htmlunit, but it doesn't work (tried diff browserversions .. still no luck).

one way could be to embed a webbrowser in java , but hvn't had any success with it ?

any suggestions or some alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [adword's api](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/developer/index.html) and [[Client library for Java,Python ect]](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/clientlibraries.html).

Comment: adword api won't help here - it has quotas, we need to use the external tool which is without restrictions.